# issue with javascript filter method on my array?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following error when using filter function on my json_encoded PHP array.

```
Error in render: "TypeError: this.globals.navLinks.filter is not a function"
```

This is my array original shape before using json_encode and passing it as a prop to my component where I use filter function.

```
$globals['navLinks'] = [
            'Inicio' => [ 'name' => 'Inicio', 'url' => '/' , 'hasSublinks' => false, 'sublinks' => [], 'isVisible' => true ],
            'Quienes somos' => [ 'name' => 'Quienes somos', 'url' => '/#quienes-somos' , 'hasSublinks' => false, 'sublinks' => [], 'isVisible' => true ],
            'Donde estamos' => [ 'name' => 'Donde estamos', 'url' => '/#donde-estamos' ,'hasSublinks' => false, 'sublinks' => [], 'isVisible' => true ],
            'Contactar' => [ 'name' => 'Contactar', 'url' => '/contactar' , 'hasSublinks' => false, 'sublinks' => [], 'isVisible' => true ],
            'Descuentos' => [ 'name' => 'Descuentos', 'url' => '/descuentos' , 'hasSublinks' => true, 'sublinks' => $discounts, 'isVisible' => true ],
            'Eventos' => [ 'name' => 'Eventos', 'url' => '/eventos' , 'hasSublinks' => true, 'sublinks' => $events, 'isVisible' => true ],
        ];
```

And the function which gives me error.

```
visibleLinks: function(){
        return this.globals.navLinks.filter(link => link.isVisible && !link.hasSublinks || link.isVisible && link.hasSublinks && link.sublinks.length > 0);
    }
```

Any idea how I can filter my array then? why am I getting this error?

Comment: What is `this` supposed to be and does it have a property called `globals` on it? EDIT: also, what does `this.globals` contain?

Comment: did you parse your JSON? It still may be stringified

Comment: you probably need `this["$globals"].navLinks.filter`

Comment: globals is a vue prop, it's value is a PHP array I used json_encode function on.